# Validate Record Data from Records in another table

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I have 2 tables: Employee, and Regions. Each Employee can be assigned to one region, and each region can have multiple employees. However, I only want the data entered into the Employee record for 'Region' to be one that exists in the Region table. How do I do this?

List of Regions: Northeast, Southeast, Central, Northwest, Southwest

Using MySQL, MySQL Workbench, and Amazon RDS

Comment: as you have only 5 you could use a enum filed or use a foreign key consstraint

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you add a foreign key constraint to the region table

> ```
> CREATE tABLE Region (region  VARCHAR(55) Primary KEY  NOT NULL)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Region VALUES ('Northeast'), ('Southeast'), ('Central'), ('Northwest'), ('Southwest')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE employee (id bigint Primary KEY auto_increment
> , refregion  VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL
> , 
>     CONSTRAINT FK_RmploxxRegion FOREIGN KEY (refregion)
>     REFERENCES Region(region))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO employee VALUES (NULL,'Northpole')
> ```
>
> ```
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_1115468314`.`employee`, CONSTRAINT `FK_RmploxxRegion` FOREIGN KEY (`refregion`) REFERENCES `Region` (`region`))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO employee VALUES (NULL,'Northeast')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM employee
> ```
>
> ```
> id | refregion
> -: | :--------
>  2 | Northeast
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6bab994aab170dd6b865145cb0248b7b)*